# How to open a file that is input by the user in command-line?

Tags: python

So if the user is running my file (test.py) from the command line, and wants to open a file *in* that program, how do I open it?

Say if the user writes 'test.py < file2.py' in command line, how do I then open file2.py in test.py?

I know it's something to do with sys.argv.

Comment: `<` will pipe `file2.py` into `sys.stdin` (which you could read from inside `test.py`, if you wanted) -- alternatively, `test.py file2.py` will call `test.py` with an *argument* of `file2.py` which you can access with `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `sys.argv`

> sys.argv
>
> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty string.

it should be :

```
python test.py your_file
```

sys.argv[0], its the script name that is `test.py`

sys.argv[1], will have `your_file`

now you can use `open` built-in to open file:

```
my_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
```

suppose you entered the file and number both:

```
python test.py your_file 2
```

here :
sys.argv[0] -> test.py

sys.argv[1] -> your_file

sys.argv[2] -> number that is 2

Comment: Let's say that the user can enter a number of specifiers in command line, and the location of the file itself can change in the index. In that case, I can't specify the exact number []...

Answer (score 0):

Hackaholic's answer is pretty good.
However, if you just want to redirect input from file using "< file2.py", then you can use [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Note that redirecting the input essentially means that the input is available on stdin and you can read it using raw_input.
I found this [example](http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/python/eofexceptionrawinput/) which is similar to what you are trying:

```
while True:
  try:
    value = raw_input()
    do_stuff(value) # next line was found 
  except (EOFError):
    break #end of file reached
```

Update:
Even more elegant would be to use the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599639/whats-perfect-counterpart-in-python-for-while-not-eof):

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    do_something()
```