# Implementing readline() in Python

Tags: python-2.7

If we consider

```
f=open('foo.txt')
x= f.readline()
print x
```

Then we get the first line of file foo.txt.

Now consider:

```
<code>
f=open('foo.txt')
while (x = f.readline()) != '': # Read one line till EOF and do something
     .... do something
f.close()
</code>
```

This gives a syntax error at

```
x=f.readline().
```

I am relatively new to Python and I cannot figure out the problem. One encounters this kind of expression often in C.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Python, as assignment is not an expression and can not be used in a condition. What exactly do you want to achieve with this? Have you tried just `for x in f:`?

Comment: yes I know about `for x in f:` but I just wanted to see if a C like construction works out or not. The expression versus assignment clarifies it. Than you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have answer here [What's perfect counterpart in Python for "while not eof"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599639/whats-perfect-counterpart-in-python-for-while-not-eof)

In short you can check whether line is still valid on each loop like this

```
with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    while True:
        line=f.readline()
        if not line: break
        process(line)
```

Or you can use python built in function to iterate over file like this

```
with open('file') as myFile:
    for line in myFile:
        do_something()
```