# Why is this while loop only doing the first loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to produce some mechanical stress info from windspeed data for a crane boom when it is between 0 and 90 degrees, with data from each angle saved into it's own file. I have the script working fine when doing just one file/angle, however when I try and use any sort of loop to do it for all angles it will create the files, but only the first has any data in it. I am a beginner and am not very savvy with Python, so I was hoping someone could spot something simple I have missed. I have included a short example file of the source data: [Windspeed source file - cut down](https://ufile.io/e0s0v)

```
import math
file = open("C:/Users/Jacob/Desktop/BOM Data/HD01D_Data_074272_999999999523840.txt", 'r')

boomDirection = 0
vaneSpeed = 120
maxShear = 75.97043478
maxVonMises = 500.0216811

while boomDirection < 91:
    data_file = open("Bolt Stress - " + str(boomDirection) + " Degrees.csv", 'w')
    line = file.readline()
    line = file.readline()
    while line != '':
        try:
            if len(line.split(','))>1:                                      
                windSpeedHigh = int(line.split(',')[19])
                windSpeedLow = int(line.split(',')[22])
                windDirection = int(line.split(',')[14])
                relSpeedHigh = math.sin(math.radians((90-(boomDirection - windDirection))))*windSpeedHigh
                relSpeedLow = math.sin(math.radians((90-(boomDirection - windDirection))))*windSpeedLow
                VonMisesHigh = (maxVonMises/vaneSpeed)* relSpeedHigh
                VonMisesLow = (maxVonMises/vaneSpeed)* relSpeedLow
                data_file.write(str(round(VonMisesHigh,1)) + ('\n'))
                data_file.write(str(round(VonMisesLow,1)) + ('\n'))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        line = file.readline()
    data_file.close()
    boomDirection = boomDirection + 1
```

Comment: after the first file `line != '':` this condition will always be false.

Comment: Can you please show the input file data?

Comment: Yes I remember the last line in the source file being blank, which is why I included that as the point to stop. I'll try and reopen the source file inside the first loop

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599639/what-is-the-perfect-counterpart-in-python-for-while-not-eof) - to detect an End of File. You will have to change your loop though.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! I didn't tell it to re-open the source data file from the start each time. Cheers